# Sorting of array returned by a NSFileManager's subpathsAtPath: method

Tags: ios, file, sorting, nsfilemanager

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:storagePath] returns a array of strings representing the paths for all the items in 'storagePath'. In my tests, this array always looks alphabetically sorted by file name, but in the docs I can't find anything that tells me that this sorting is guaranteed. If I know the array is sorted I can search it more efficiently.

Anyone know if this array is guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: If it is not documented then it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* fetchResults = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:storagePath];
[fetchResults sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* a, NSString* b){
    NSString* a1 = [a lastPathComponent];
    NSString* b1 = [b lastPathComponent];
    return [a1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare b1];
    }
];
```

When everything is in alphabetical to begin with, this sort will run rather fast, meaning you can gain peace of mind that you'll always have the alphabetical order you need, without wasting too many CPU cycles to get it.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm doing haha. I'd love to be able to skip this though because it seems like wasted work.

Comment: There's everything right about your skepticism that wants a GUARANTEE of an alphabetical sort. Since you're not getting it from the docs, you end up exactly with what you want by sorting with a comparator like this. Besides, if the results are already in alphabetical order, this block will be making exactly one pass through the array (every comparison result will just say "good, move on"), which is probably going to take negligible time. To me it seems a small price to pay to rigorously satisfy your justified skeptical demand that alphabetical order be guaranteed.

Comment: I re-read the NSFileManager class reference too, and couldn't find any guarantee that the results would be sorted either. You may also consider using the methods that return NSURL's (like contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:) as you have a few more convenience methods and hooks to work with compared to simple file path strings